# bigquery "Unable to save query. Try again in 30 seconds."

Tags: google-bigquery

I keep getting this error when I try to save a query from the web interface. I don't know what kind of relevant information I should provide. I can run the query and see results. I think I have minimal permissions on this project, but I've been able to create a dataset and have saved queries to it before.

Comment: I've started seeing this today as well.

Comment: There is a known issue with saved queries and the minimal IAM roles. You should still be able to save personal queries (in spite of the error message). We're actively working to fix this.

Comment: This is causing a lot of confusion in our teams. @AdamLydick - any update? It's been over 5 months. I've filed an issue here -> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37610860

Comment: Yes, I expect this to roll out next week (and includes proper support for BigQuery IAM roles as well).